# dota 2 graphics problem in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, steam, graphic-card, amd-graphics

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 in my laptop. I then installed steam and finally dota 2.
But the graphics are very bad.
I have AMD Radeon 7400 in my laptop. It seems like dota 2 is not running through my graphic card.
I don't even know whether after installing Ubuntu I have my graphic card driver installed or not.

Do I have to manually install the graphic card driver or it is already installed? And if so, how to enable it so that dota 2 runs with some good textures.

Answer (score 0):

Install proprietary driver `sudo apt-get install fglrx` then run `aticonfig --initial` and reboot.

Comment: i tried this also. when i did this, whole graphics went very low, nothng was visible properly. and then i had to reinstall ubuntu to fix this :(

Comment: You may also try to install drivers from AMD website, check 3.1 in this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD